# Hexadecimal data image from PHP 5.59 on Linux not in correct format

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

I get unexpected value expection in PHP logs. When I query hex image data in PHP from Sql server in Linux, the data is different from what I get in Windows. ALso im unable to use hex2bin in Linux, I am able to convert it windows and display the image perfectly where as the data in Linux shows up something like below and is non readable and hex2bin throws up some even digit error. If I try return retrieve the value it says malformed utf8 characters. 
'

����JFIF``��C         $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222���'

How can I get the correct data. The data type in SQL server is Image and data is stored in hex format like this 0xFFF. I tried using php5. 59, 5.63 but it's the same result.

Comment: Which PHP driver are you using to connect to server?

Comment: Im using php-sqlsrv and freetds

Comment: php-sqlsrv supporting PHP 5.6 doesn't have any support on Linux and is also requires Microsoft ODBC driver, can you upgrade to PHP 7.0 + ?

Comment: also do you have a repro script we can use?